# How can green algae be both multicellular and unicellular?

Tags: taxonomy

How can green algae be both multicellular and unicellular? What are the cases in which it can be both uni and multi cellular?

Comment: "Green algae "is a broad group. You should add details to your question. And why the "organic-chemistry" tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because *Algae* are represented across four kingdoms, namely *Bacteria* ([unicellular prokaryotes](http://www.encyclopedia.com/topic/bacteria.aspx)), *Plantae* ([multicellular eukaryotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plant)), Chromista ([multicellular eukaryotes](http://www.ucmp.berkeley.edu/chromista/chromista.html)), and Protozoa ([single-celled eukaryotes](http://www.encyclopedia.com/topic/Protozoa.aspx)).

For example, *I. Chlorophyta* is unicellular:

[image: Unicellular]
<sup>*I. Chlorophyta*. Source: [University of Wisconsin](http://www4.uwsp.edu/biology/courses/botlab/Lab20a.htm)</sup>

While kelp can become huge and can form underwater forests:

[image: Kelp]
<sup>Kelp. Source: [Nature](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v461/n7267/full/4611066a.html)</sup>

**Reference**
[Guiry, *J Phycol* 2012; **48**, 1057–63](http://seaweed.ie/guiry/pdfs/How_Many_Published.pdf)

Comment: -1. The taxonomic classification (the four kingdoms mentioned) utilized here and the corresponding habituses are at best inaccurate or incomplete. Moreover the question was about green algae (Chlorophyta), I don't see how this answer addresses it.